# WebSocket connection failed: WebSocket opening handshake was canceled

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, websocket

I have recently setup an EC2 instance (in a VPC with no load balancer) and admittedly the configuration is a bit odd, but it is what is required for the web application we're running.

The web server (in Haskell) is running on port 4433 (standard ports are reserved for an Apache instance) and is receiving UDP packets being broadcast from another system. I have many of the ports wide-open (just during testing) as shown here (from Security Groups):

```
Custom TCP Rule    4433     tcp 0.0.0.0/0   ✔
Custom TCP Rule    8080     tcp 0.0.0.0/0   ✔
SSH                22       tcp 0.0.0.0/0   ✔
HTTP               80       tcp 0.0.0.0/0   ✔
HTTPS              443      tcp 0.0.0.0/0   ✔
Custom UDP Rule    30090    udp 0.0.0.0/0   ✔
Custom UDP Rule    30089    udp 0.0.0.0/0   ✔
```

The JavaScript for the TCP socket makes a request to setup the socket on this same port (using the URL assigned to the AWS's public IP) and this is where the request returns the error:

> WebSocket connection to 'wss://[URL]:4433/projects/socket' failed: WebSocket opening handshake was canceled.

Binding the socket to 0.0.0.0 results in the same error.

In order to start the Haskell web server I had to reference the *internal* IP provided by AWS as it would not run when referencing the *public* IP provided by the elastic IP service. Thinking this is where the problem came in I changed my socket request to this...

```
wss://[internal ip]:4433/projects/socket
```

This changes the error:

> WebSocket connection to 'wss://[internal IP]:4433/projects/socket' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

That error makes sense to me as the internal IP is not available to the outside world.

Everything that I've read on websockets on AWS involves an ELB (Elastic Load Balancer) and I am not in need of one of those. I have tried all of the things in all of the currently posted answers (some of the questions haven't even gotten answers) on SO to no avail. I also setup a support case with Amazon (nearly 24 hours ago) which hasn't received a response.

### Additional Info

Navigating to `http://[URL]:4433/projects/socket` yields 'WebSocket Available' where the URL is the one we wish to use as well as the Public DNS provided by AWS.

Running `netstat -plunt` reveals the following:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 [internal IP]:8080      0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 [internal IP]:4433      0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      -
udp        0      0 [internal IP]:30089     0.0.0.0:*                           -
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:30090           0.0.0.0:*                           -
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:11950           0.0.0.0:*                           -
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           -
udp6       0      0 :::38450                :::*                                -
```

Has anyone had a similar problem with websockets on AWS? If so, how did you solve the problem?

Comment: I don't have much experience with AWS, but the question is a glory to read! (I feel like I found a diamond on SO :)

Comment: Just to know, are you using self-signed certificate? I've experienced similar issue with self-signed certificate where I had to import the self-signed cert in the truststore in an application in another language.

Comment: No, the certificate is not self-signed. @Samar

Comment: Based on your netstat output, isn't it possible to bind to 0.0.0.0 in your haskell web server?

Comment: I have tried to do that and it fails in the same way @Samar.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I'm sorry that I can not be useful much and I missed you mentioning about binding to 0.0.0.0 in original question but I would still recommend you to:
- test with plain socket i.e. disabling wss on 4433
- if it works, its SSL for sure so use openssl to verify that appropriate SSL certificate is being served and for valid domain (you can start with openssl s_client -connect internal_ip:4433, I suppose)
- if plain socket does not work, its most likely an issue at AWS level

Comment: @Sarmar thank you for trying to help. I verified the appropriate SSL cert is being used just as you have suggested. I continue to be at a loss here and the AWS folks say that I have everything setup and working correctly. In other words, they don't know either.

Comment: I feel some good news are headed our way, *am I right Sam?*  - @JayBlanchard

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There was an SSL certificate mismatch between the Haskell server and the Apache server.

The Haskell server had to be rebuilt with information concerning the new certificates for the instance. Further complicating this the proper SSL library (`libssl0.9.8 libssl-dev`) was not installed on the EC2 instance which was causing me problems during the rebuild of the Haskell server. Knowing an EC2 instance is a "blank canvas" makes the lack of that installation my fault.

Once I had the `libssl` installed I was able to rebuild the Haskell server with it pointing to the new certificates. Once the certificates "matched" the websocket issue disappeared.

Just to reiterate, ours is a unique situation. We have an Apache server (ports 80 and 443) and a Haskell server (ports 8080 and 4433) which communicate with each other, performing a pub-sub operation over websockets. A certificate mismatch between the two servers (it would not have mattered what type, it could have been multiple Apache instances) caused an SSL warning. Any warning from SSL will tear-down any attempt to establish or maintain a websocket (hence the handshake canceled message).

[Another StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23404160/why-does-my-wss-websockets-over-ssl-tls-connection-immediately-disconnect-w) provided some clues that were of tremendous help during this process. More specifically this warning -

> The key to the problem is this: **If your SSL certificate causes a warning of any sort, wss:// WebSocket connections will immediately fail**, and there is no canonical way to detect this.

Comment: *Glad to hear it Sam!* Another happy ending ;-)

Comment: *Thanks Ralph!* And I feel much lighter without that weight on my shoulders @Fred-ii-

Answer (score -1):

I ran into this error when using websockets from a blob-based webworker from a file:// URL. I suspect running in a webserver might fix this; I solved it by turning off SSL while I debug.

Answer (score -1):

This error can come if `websocket` url is not properly put in `frontend`

check this answer [websockets in https connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17334319/setting-up-a-websocket-on-apache/51770475#51770475)

correct way of putting frontend url is `"wss://example.com/wss/"`

wrong way of putting frontend url is

```
wss://example.com:8080/wss/ -> port no should not be mentioned
ws://example.com/wss/ -> url should start with wss only.
wss://example.com/wss -> url should end with / -> most important
```