# Failed: WebSocket opening handshake timed out (Amazon AWS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, amazon-elb

I am facing issue with websocket. 
Websocket is working fine with http.

But when we tried to access it from HTTPS we are facing failed: `WebSocket opening handshake timed out error`

Its working fine with http.

Comment: Maybe you are behind a firewall that only opens port 80 to the outside? For https you need port 443.

Comment: i have enabled port 443 also on ELB

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30732269/websocket-connection-failed-websocket-opening-handshake-was-canceled

Comment: Although your question looks valid at first sight it does not meet SO [minimal site criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It will fit better at a sister site. You can select one or more from [> here <](https://stackexchange.com/sites) or update your question to meet the requirements.