# WebSocket opening handshake timed out php Ratxet websocket

Tags: php, websocket, phpwebsocket

I'm creating my first websocket, it works locally with ws, now I uploaded it to a server and uploaded all files and execute the websocket from ssh.

And I get this error: WebSocket opening handshake timed out

I tried adding this line to httpd.conf

`ProxyPass /wss2/ ws://xxxxxxx:12345/`

but still does not work.

```php
var conn = new WebSocket('wss://xxxxxxxxx:12345');

        conn.onopen = function(e) {
            console.log("Connection established!");
            conn.send(
                JSON.stringify({
                    'type':'socket',
                    'id':'<?php echo $this->session->id; ?>'
                })
            );
        };
```

This is the console error I get:

```
dashboard:430 WebSocket connection to 'wss://xxxxxxxxxx:12345/' failed: WebSocket opening handshake timed out
```

Comment: Is that port allowed? Meaning opened?

Comment: @ReynierPM to be sure was not that, i changed it to 8080, still same issue.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30732269/websocket-connection-failed-websocket-opening-handshake-was-canceled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this,

First i changed the port to 8080, (I don't think that was necessary.)

Changed the url connection to:

```
wss://xxxxxxxxx/wss2/:8080
```

('Cause the ProxyPass)

And it works.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Apache web server (2.4 or above), enable these modules in httpd.conf file

1. [mod_proxy.so](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html)
2. [mod_proxy_wstunnel.so](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_wstunnel.html)

If you don't know how to enable, use below commands

- sudo a2enmod proxy_wstunnel
- sudo a2enmod proxy

Then Add this setting to your httpd.conf file

```
ProxyPass /wss2/ ws://ratchet.mydomain.org:8888/
```

Use this URL in your JavaSscript call when you want a WSS connection:

```
var ws = new WebSocket("wss://ratchet.mydomain.org/wss2/NNN");
```

Restart Apache web server and make sure that your Ratchet worker (web socket connection) is open before applying the settings (telnet hostname port).