# accessing mosquitto via port 443 and apache

Tags: docker, apache, mqtt, mosquitto

I am running a MQTT Mosquitto server listening on port 8883 using TLS in a docker container with name 'mosquitto'.

In another docker container in the same network I am running an Apache webserver with a webpage at my_domain (at port 443).

The Apache should forward all requests to `my_domain/mosquitto` to the Mosquitto broker.
using my_domain/mosquitto. Thus I add

```
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyPass /mosquitto ws://mosquitto:8883
  ProxyPassReverse /mosquitto ws://mosquitto:8883
```

to my `httpd.conf` which redirects https-browser-calls to `my_domain/mosquitto` to mosquitto.
This of course result in an OpenSSL error at Mosquitto.

But using the MQTT client (python) results in `Name or service not known`

What I am doing wrong?

P.S.:
The SSL keys / certificates for the Apache and the Mosquitto are different.
When disabling the webserver, redirect the Mosquitto to port 443 via docker the connection is working.

Comment: Are you telling the python client to use the `/mosquitto` path? the default for MQTT over websockets is `/mqtt`

Comment: I am telling the python client `/mosquitto` (= `my_domain/mosquitto`, I also tried `ws://my_domain/mosquitto`) because I have that `ProxyPass` in the `httpd.conf` of Apache for the sub directory `mosquitto`.
In the config of mosquitto I have not enabled websockets. As I understood this is for using Mosquitto with browsers.

Comment: There 2 are two options I have found which I unfortunately cannot use:
1. Not using TLS and a Apache module for MQTT redirection
2. TLS termination in the Apache

Comment: You MUST use MQTT over Websockets in this case

Answer (score 1):

To use a HTTP reverse proxy (Apache) to proxy for a MQTT broker you must use MQTT of Websockets (because WebSocket connections are bootstrapped over HTTP).

A native MQTT connection will just not work as Apache has no way of understanding the native protocol format.

You will need to enable a Websocket Listener in Mosquitto and tell the client to make a websocket connect.

You should also probably be using `/mqtt` not `/mosquitto` as the path to proxy as this is the default for WebSocket connects

Comment: So  
  
`mosquitto.conf`:  
    listener 8883
    protocol websockets
    require_certificate true
    ... 
    
`httpd.conf: (mosquitto is the name of the docker container = hostname)  
    <VirtualHost *:443> 
        ProxyPreserveHost On 
        ProxyPass /mqtt wss://mosquitto:8883
        ProxyPassReverse /mqtt wss://mosquitto:8883 
    </VirtualHost> 
    
client: (e.g. python / paho.mqtt)
    port = 443
    broker = 'wss://domain_name/mqtt' 
    client = mqtt_client.Client(transport="websockets")
    client.tls_set( ...)
    client.connect(broker, port)
    
???

Comment: By the way: There is a Apache module for MQTT protocol processing - but this works only for none TLS connections.
https://blog.benjamin-cabe.com/2015/10/01/how-to-run-your-web-server-and-mqtt-websockets-broker-on-the-same-port

Comment: No there isn't. If you read that blog post it is still using MQTT over WebSockets, it's just terminating the WebsSocket connection at Apache and then forwarding the native connection on to the broker. But given most brokers natively support WebSockets these days the module is no longer required.

Comment: Activating `mod_proxy_wstunnel`, using `ProxyPass `/wss/ ws://mosquitto:8883`and `ServerName subdomain` (have now own subdomain for MQTT) did not help.

The Apache Log does not show entries when trying to connect with the MQTT client (only by a browser). 
I have tried all mentioned combinations from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17334319/setting-up-a-websocket-on-apache  - accept the SSL termination in Apache by providing the MQTT certificates to it.

Comment: Finally It was possible using SNI and a dedicated proxy service which does not care about the content and thus, does not need to understand it.

Comment: This should now be possible with ALPN and something like NGINX's stream proxy, but SNI is just about which host name to pick

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I am using a own subdomain for MQTT now and thus, I can use SNI. Indeed am using NGINX's stream proxy. ALPN also works for the proxy but some MQTT clients have problems with it.