# Ratchet + nginx + SSL/secure websocket

Tags: ssl, nginx, websocket, ratchet

I've been trying to run Ratchet.io over SSL (this problem: [php ratchet websocket SSL connect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16979793/php-ratchet-websocket-ssl-connect/20228204#20228204)).

My webserver is running at myhost.mobi, and I have created a separate virtual host for websocket service "wws.myhost.mobi".

My web socket:

```
$webSock = new React\Socket\Server($loop);
$webSock->listen(8080, '0.0.0.0');
$webServer = new Ratchet\Server\IoServer(
    new Ratchet\Http\HttpServer(
        new Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer(
            new Ratchet\Wamp\WampServer(
                $pusher
            )
        )
    ),
    $webSock
);
```

My nginx config (I'm on nginx 1.5.8):

```
upstream websocketserver {
        server localhost:8080;
}

server {
    server_name wss.myapp.mobi;

    listen 443;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/myapp-mobi-ssl.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/myapp-mobi.key;

    access_log /var/log/wss-access-ssl.log;
    error_log /var/log/wss-error-ssl.log;
    location / {
                proxy_pass http://websocketserver;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                proxy_set_header Host $host;

                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
                proxy_read_timeout 86400; # neccessary to avoid websocket timeout disconnect
                proxy_redirect off;
        }
}
```

My client-side script:

```
var conn = new ab.Session('wss://wss.myapp.mobi', function(o) {

    // ...

}, function() {
    console.warn('WebSocket connection closed');
}, {
    skipSubprotocolCheck: true
});
```

So, when I load the page in Firefox, I see an outgoing connection to wss://wss.myapp.mobi:8080/, which is hanging (the spinner) and never completes or dies. I do not see any trace of request arriving on the backend in the logs.

What am I missing there?

Thanks!

**EDIT** I have realized that I should be connecting to *wss://wss.myapp.mobi*, but now I am getting "101 Switching Protocols" status.

**EDIT 2** Everything is working now with the config above. "101 Switching Protocols" status turns out to be a normal message. PROBLEM SOLVED!

Comment: you really helped me with this question. I wasn't able to get websockets  to work with SSL in Nginx.
Turns out I was missing the proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https; directive in the configuration - and your question made me add it.
Thanks!

Comment: This question is solved (see edit), but the solution is not explained.

Comment: Could you post the detailed solution as an answer?

Answer (score 8):

By checking question edit history, it is clear that, the configuration in the question was correct, **temuri** was trying to connect from client with port set in,

```
upstream websocketserver {
        server localhost:8080;
}
```

but this code block tells Nginx there is a tcp server running on port 8080, represents it as `websocketserver` alias, but the running server is not accessible to public.

Check the below configuration,

```
server {
    server_name wss.myapp.mobi;

    listen 443;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/myapp-mobi-ssl.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/myapp-mobi.key;

    access_log /var/log/wss-access-ssl.log;
    error_log /var/log/wss-error-ssl.log;
    location / {
                proxy_pass http://websocketserver;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                proxy_set_header Host $host;

                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
                proxy_read_timeout 86400; # neccessary to avoid websocket timeout disconnect
                proxy_redirect off;
        }
}
```

this configuration binds the domain `wss.myapp.mobi` to port 443 enabling ssl and `proxy`ing the requests to the local websocket server via `proxy_pass` directive, rest directives are for connection upgrades handling.

So the websocket server can be accessed from browser client with

```
// connect through binded domain
// instead of wss.myapp.mobi:8080 which will not work
var url = 'wss://wss.myapp.mobi';
```

Comment: You are the man! I spent several days  trying to figure this out.  It's so insane because var url = 'ws://wss.myapp.mobi:8080' absolutely works butvar url = 'wss://wss.myapp.mobi:8080' does not.  Removing the port number fixed my frustration. THANK YOU!!!