# Ratchet Websocket not working in https mode in apache server

Tags: apache, websocket, mod-proxy, ratchet

Hi i have followed the instruction given by the below question for apache server for Websocket in **https** mode.

[php ratchet websocket SSL connect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16979793/php-ratchet-websocket-ssl-connect?rq=1#answer-28393526)

My Websocket server was working fine.But when my websocket server was killed due to some reason after that it was not working in **https** mode anymore.But its working fine in http mode as it was working before.

Comment: Was your ws connection open before applying the settings and restarting the server?

Comment: For the first time when i did this it was working.Now its not working.

Comment: Please provide the ProxyPass config and client-side connection for us.