# Ratchet websocket SSL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl, websocket, ratchet

I use Ratchet websocket on my server. It is working well without SSL but i need to make it work with SSL.

I've read this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16979793/php-ratchet-websocket-ssl-connect). Unfortunately the support of my PAAS don't use httpd.conf. They advised me to add the ProxyPass straight in the .htaccess.

> Regarding adding the following line in httpd.conf file then here I
>   would like to inform that we are not using httpd on the server as
>   server is Debian based and we are using Apache web server. I believe
>   you can use the same line in htaccess file or it would be better if
>   you can consult with the developer regarding this.

```
# ProxyPass for Ratchet with SSL
ProxyPass /wss2/ ws://127.198.132.141:8000/

# Preventing the app from being indexed
Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow"

# Use the front controller as index file. It serves as a fallback solution when
# every other rewrite/redirect fails (e.g. in an aliased environment without
# mod_rewrite). Additionally, this reduces the matching process for the
# start page (path "/") because otherwise Apache will apply the rewriting rules
# to each configured DirectoryIndex file (e.g. index.php, index.html, index.pl).
DirectoryIndex app.php

# By default, Apache does not evaluate symbolic links if you did not enable this
# feature in your server configuration. Uncomment the following line if you
# install assets as symlinks or if you experience problems related to symlinks
# when compiling LESS/Sass/CoffeScript assets.
# Options FollowSymlinks

# Disabling MultiViews prevents unwanted negotiation, e.g. "/app" should not resolve
# to the front controller "/app.php" but be rewritten to "/app.php/app".
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    [...]
```

Unfortunately Adding ProxyPass /wss2/ ws://127.198.132.141:8000/ is crashing the server as if the .htaccess was incorrect.

Do you have any solutions or hints?

**UPDATE :**

From what i understand we can't use ProxyPass in .htaccess it should be only used in the server configuration or virtual host configuration.

I tried to explain it to the support but they do not seem to understand.

> So apparently it is forbidden to use ProxyPass in .htaccess.
>
> "ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse are available only in the server
>   config and virtual host contexts."
>
> Therefore if you can't add this line in the server config, could it be
>   added in the virtual host contexts?

Their answer :

> As I have again reviewed all the settings on the server level which
>   includes the Apache modules and Firewall rules to make the Ratchet
>   websockets able to run on the server also the rules which we have
>   added in Firewall indicates that all the traffic from outside is
>   allowed on the port 8000 and I believe which should be sufficient to
>   allow outside connections for websocket.
>
> As of now, it seems like you are trying to make the connection using
>   the different port (in case of https). As we have reviewed the server
>   settings and configurations and all seems to be good.
>
> It would be highly appreciated if you can involves the developer in
>   this process so he can guide you better as he know the code level
>   things much better.

Right now attempting to connect with wss will throw :

> WebSocket connection to 'wss://127.198.132.141/wss2/' failed:
>   WebSocket opening handshake was canceled

While using http with ws is working well.

Comment: did you fix this? I have the same issue

Comment: Hi, unfortunately not since i can't configure much on my host. I had to stop using SSL for now. I'm still interested to find a solution ;).

Comment: I fix using port 8888. I have tried with 8080 without success. I also write an aswer, hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, it is indeed one of the solution as long the port is not used by the server. Unfortunately since i'm using a PAAS solution those ports are already used for some of their services. Nevermind i'll validate your answer ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your virtual host add :

`ProxyPass /wss2/ ws://yourdomain.xxx:8888/`
(try with port 8888)

**do not forget to restart apache service**

virtual host example:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        <Directory /var/www/html/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        <IfModule mod_dir.c>
            DirectoryIndex index.php index.pl index.cgi index.html index.xhtml index.htm
        </IfModule>

SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/yourdomain.xxx/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/yourdomain.xxx/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
ServerName yourdomain.xxx
ProxyPass /wss2/ ws://yourdomain.xxx:8888/
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Here you can find a full working example
https://github.com/ratchetphp/Ratchet/issues/100