# PHP websocket on SSL with proxy_wsTunnel - Apache

Tags: php, apache, websocket, ratchet

I have a php websocket server running but I want to connect to it via https. This is my JS: `var conn = new WebSocket('wss://81.169.228.159:3671/wss2');`

And this is my apache config:

`ProxyPass /wss2/ ws://domain:3671/`

I have `proxy` and `proxy_wstunnel` enabled.

So, what am I doing wrong?

ERROR LOG:

```
[Mon Mar 13 04:38:04.228450 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 6683] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.0.2g configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Mar 13 04:38:04.228471 2017] [core:notice] [pid 6683] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Mon Mar 13 12:42:39.475641 2017] [:error] [pid 12432] [client 195.169.9.201:8546] script '/var/www/html/luukwuijster.io/phpinfo.php' not found or unable to stat
[Mon Mar 13 12:56:25.370986 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 6683] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon Mar 13 12:56:26.539948 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 26932] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.0.2g configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Mar 13 12:56:26.539972 2017] [core:notice] [pid 26932] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Mon Mar 13 13:06:36.280229 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 26932] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon Mar 13 13:06:37.473220 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 27256] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.0.2g configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Mar 13 13:06:37.473248 2017] [core:notice] [pid 27256] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Mon Mar 13 13:19:52.144983 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 27256] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon Mar 13 13:19:53.235045 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 27775] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.0.2g configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Mar 13 13:19:53.235083 2017] [core:notice] [pid 27775] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Mon Mar 13 13:22:21.467607 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 27775] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon Mar 13 13:22:22.618416 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 27911] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.0.2g configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Mar 13 13:22:22.618455 2017] [core:notice] [pid 27911] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Mon Mar 13 13:28:08.356148 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 27911] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon Mar 13 13:28:09.546926 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 28540] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.0.2g configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Mar 13 13:28:09.546964 2017] [core:notice] [pid 28540] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Mon Mar 13 13:35:26.856446 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 28540] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon Mar 13 13:35:28.532498 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 29153] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.0.2g configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Mar 13 13:35:28.532541 2017] [core:notice] [pid 29153] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Mon Mar 13 13:46:19.084561 2017] [ssl:error] [pid 29170] [client 208.93.152.93:54712] AH02042: rejecting client initiated renegotiation
[Mon Mar 13 13:57:14.410892 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 29153] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon Mar 13 13:57:16.465381 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 29927] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.0.2g configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Mar 13 13:57:16.465424 2017] [core:notice] [pid 29927] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Mon Mar 13 14:00:03.312882 2017] [:error] [pid 29936] [client 81.169.228.159:33706] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: text in /var/www/html/luukwuijster.io/slack/cronofy/huiswerk.php on line 9
```

Comment: Certificates are domain based and cannot work with IP addresses.

Comment: I now changed it to my domain. And it's still not working

Comment: Have you checked your error log?

Comment: Yes I did, Or atleast, I checked the access.log. And there was nothing usefull in it

Comment: Check the error.log

Comment: I added the log to my post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137940/discussion-between-luuk-wuijster-and-jay-blanchard).

Comment: I am not in a place where I can chat this morning.

Comment: [Mon Mar 13 13:46:19.084561 2017] [ssl:error] [pid 29170] [client 208.93.152.93:54712] AH02042: rejecting client initiated renegotiation Start by researching this error.

Comment: Okay, I will do that.

Comment: Okay, I tried to do some research about that error, but there is not much information about it.... :/

Comment: Have you followed the basic setup [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wstunnel)?

Comment: I am not using the JS package. I use the apache `proxy_wstunnel` module

Comment: Okay, so after changing some ports and changing some other things I finaly managed to do it. Its solved now :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that you have a `React\Socket\Server` listening on port `8080` (aka `php push-server.php`). The tutorial on the ratchet website should get you up to this point.

I also assume that you have already configured and loaded the `proxy` and `proxy_wstunnel` apache modules as mentioned in the question.

---

Below is the config I personally use to achieve a WebSocket connection.

I use `/ws/` instead of the `/wss2/` mentioned in the tutorial for a better looking URL. Feel free to adjust the config as necessary.

**Apache Config**

```
#SSL (Secure)                                                                                                                                                                                                               
<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot /FILE_PATH_TO_WEBROOT
    ServerName local.sitename.com
    ServerAlias local.sitename.com
    <Directory /FILE_PATH_TO_WEBROOT>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all 
        php_flag display_errors On
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/ssl/.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/ssl/.key

    ProxyRequests Off 
    ProxyPass "/ws/"  "ws://local.sitename.com:8080/"
</VirtualHost>

#NON-SSL (Insecure)
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /FILE_PATH_TO_WEBROOT
    ServerName local.sitename.com
    ServerAlias local.sitename.com
    <Directory /FILE_PATH_TO_WEBROOT>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all 
        php_flag display_errors On
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    ProxyRequests Off 
    ProxyPass "/ws/"  "ws://local.sitename.com:8080/"
</VirtualHost>
```

**Secure JavaScript Socket Connection**

```
var conn = new WebSocket('wss://local.sitename.com/ws/');
```

**Insecure JavaScript Socket Connection**

```
var conn = new WebSocket('ws://local.sitename.com/ws/');
```

Comment: Yes! Thanks! that's so much better then my own "solution". It works perfectly