# Websocket php SSL connect Apache2 2.4

Tags: javascript, php, websocket

I want to know how to connect websocket with SSL connection.
  my apache2 configuration is below:

```
 ProxyPass /test/fr/pageJsWebsocket/  ws://127.0.0.1:8081/ retry=0 keepalive=On
 ProxyPassReverse /test/fr/pageJsWebsocket/  ws://127.0.0.1:8081/ retry=0
```

in my client site :

```
 var conn = new WebSocket ('wss://mydomain.com/test/fr/pageJsWebsocket/')
```

My configuration looks like:

```
SSLProxyEngine On
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyRequests Off # Websocket proxy
# wss redirects to working ws protocol ProxyPass /testPage/
ws://mydomain.com:8081/web/fr ProxyPassReverse /testPage/
ws://mydomain.com:8081/web/fr
```

The error I am getting is:

```
JS file: var conn = new WebSocket ('wss://mydomain.com:8081/web/fr/testPage/') Error: failed: WebSocket opening handshake timed out
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP websocket on SSL with proxy\_wsTunnel - Apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42764084/php-websocket-on-ssl-with-proxy-wstunnel-apache)

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response, i have try this configuration i have the same error:
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Comment: Can you include the specific error that you are getting? More detail tends to increase the chance of a good answer.

Comment: i have done this configuration in my appache2
       SSLProxyEngine On
       ProxyPreserveHost On
       ProxyRequests Off
       # Websocket proxy
       # wss redirects to working ws protocol
      ProxyPass /testPage/  ws://mydomain.com:8081/web/fr
      ProxyPassReverse /testPage/  ws://mydomain.com:8081/web/fr

in JS file:

var conn = new WebSocket ('wss://mydomain.com:8081/web/fr/testPage/')

Error: failed: WebSocket opening handshake timed out

Comment: Putting the config/error information into the question itself can help people see it sooner. I went ahead and added it