# How to run websockets on Apache via wss?

Tags: apache, websocket, wss

I am trying to run a PHP chat on sockets.

Server configuration: Ubuntu-18.04-amd64, Apache/2.4.29, SSL certificate from [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/).

I use rachet. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16979793/php-ratchet-websocket-ssl-connect), [here](https://c-mh.fr/posts/websockets-en-php-plus-simple-qu-il-n-y-parait) and [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-apache-as-a-reverse-proxy-with-mod_proxy-on-ubuntu-16-04) it is described how to connect sockets through SSL connections. But I didn’t succeed.

I installed the necessary modules in Apache:

```
sudo a2enmod proxy
sudo a2enmod proxy_wstunnel
sudo a2enmod proxy_http
```

Wrote in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

```
<VirtualHost *: 443>
  <Location "/chat/">
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass /ws ws://xxxxxx.xx:999
    ProxyPassReverse /ws ws://xxxxxx.xx:999
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Opened 999 port

```
sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 999 -j ACCEPT
```

Restarted Apache

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Launched a chat server

```
php /var/www/html/chat/bin/chat-server.php
```

Wrote in the socket call script

```
websocket = new WebSocket ('wss://xxxxxx.xx/chat');
```

I tried to connect from a browser at

```
https://xxxxxx.xx/chat/
```

And got an error

> WebSocket connection to 'wss://xxxxxx.xx/chat' failed: Error during
>   WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 301

I read various tips, but still could not understand what I was doing wrong. Any attempt to change the situation creates errors 301, 300, 500 or 200.

Please tell me what I was wrong?

Comment: Have you find the answer?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I still could not start rachet chat via wss.