# PHP/Ratchet websockets - Failed to listen on "tcp://0.0.0.0:443"

Tags: php, websocket, ratchet, apache-config

I have created a websocket with PHP and Ratchet library which works locally on WAMP and I have a server on AWS running Ubuntu Debian 18.04.

I am trying to move what I created locally to the server but am getting two errors.

The first is on the client saying: `WebSocket connection to 'wss://localhost/socket' failed: WebSocket opening handshake timed out`

The second is on the server saying: `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught RuntimeException: Failed to listen on "tcp://0.0.0.0:443": Permission denied in /var/www/html/vendor/react/socket/src/TcpServer.php:165`

A simplified version of my client would be:

```
<input type="hidden" value="'.$account_id.'" id="account_id">
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var conn = new WebSocket('wss://localhost:443/socket');

    conn.onopen = function(e){
        console.log("Connection Opened!");
        var account_id = $("#account_id").val();
        var data = {account_id: account_id};
        conn.send(JSON.stringify(data));
    }
    conn.onclose = function(e){
        console.log("Connection Closed!");
    }
    conn.onmessage = function(e) {
        var data = JSON.parse(e.data);
        console.log(data);
    };
    conn.onerror = function(e){
        var data = JSON.parse(e.data);
        console.log(data);
    }
})
</script>
```

And my server is like this:

```
set_time_limit(0);

use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;
use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;
require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';

class socket implements MessageComponentInterface{
    protected $clients;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->clients = new \SplObjectStorage;
        echo 'Server Started.'.PHP_EOL;
    }

    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $socket){
        $this->clients->attach($socket);
        echo 'New connection '.$socket->resourceId.'!'.PHP_EOL;
    }
    public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $socket) {
        $this->clients->detach($socket);
        echo 'Connection '.$socket->resourceId.' has disconnected'.PHP_EOL;
    }
    public function onError(ConnectionInterface $socket, \Exception $e) {
        echo 'An error has occurred: '.$e->getMessage().'!'.PHP_EOL;
        $socket->close();
    }
    public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $json){
        echo 'Connection '.$from->resourceId.' sent '.$json.PHP_EOL;
        $data = json_decode($json, true);
        $account_id = $data['account_id'];
        
        foreach ($this->clients as $client) {
            if ($from == $client) {
                $client->send(json_encode($data));
            }
        }
    }
}

$server = IoServer::factory(
    new HttpServer(
        new WsServer(
            new socket()
        )
    ),
    443
);

$server->run();
```

I'm more of a front end developer so I'm lost when it comes to networking and apache config stuff, so here is what I've checked so far:

- Apache Modules enabled

  ```
   a2enmod proxy
   a2enmod proxy_http
   a2enmod proxy_wstunnel
  ```
- Apache Config

  ```
   /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
   <VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName dev.example.com

   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/socket            [NC]
   RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} transport=websocket    [NC]
   RewriteRule /(.*)           wss://localhost:443/$1 [P,L]

   ProxyPass / https://localhost:443/
   ProxyPassReverse / https://localhost:443/

   </VirtualHost>
  ```
- AWS security settings

[image]

### Edit

Output of `sudo netstat -ltpn`

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      12993/mysqld
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      913/systemd-resolve
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1159/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      30191/apache2
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1159/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      30191/apache2
```

### Edit 2

I've changed to port 8080 and had to allow traffic on AWS for this.

I also realized I was editing the wrong apache config file, `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` instead of `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf`.

The full file is as follows:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost _default_:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

        #   SSL Engine Switch:
        #   Enable/Disable SSL for this virtual host.
        SSLEngine on

        #   A self-signed (snakeoil) certificate can be created by installing
        #   the ssl-cert package. See
        #   /usr/share/doc/apache2/README.Debian.gz for more info.
        #   If both key and certificate are stored in the same file, only the
        #   SSLCertificateFile directive is needed.
        SSLCertificateFile  /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key

        #   Server Certificate Chain:
        #   Point SSLCertificateChainFile at a file containing the
        #   concatenation of PEM encoded CA certificates which form the
        #   certificate chain for the server certificate. Alternatively
        #   the referenced file can be the same as SSLCertificateFile
        #   when the CA certificates are directly appended to the server
        #   certificate for convinience.
        #SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crt/server-ca.crt

        #   Certificate Authority (CA):
        #   Set the CA certificate verification path where to find CA
        #   certificates for client authentication or alternatively one
        #   huge file containing all of them (file must be PEM encoded)
        #   Note: Inside SSLCACertificatePath you need hash symlinks
        #        to point to the certificate files. Use the provided
        #        Makefile to update the hash symlinks after changes.
        #SSLCACertificatePath /etc/ssl/certs/
        #SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crt/ca-bundle.crt

        #   Certificate Revocation Lists (CRL):
        #   Set the CA revocation path where to find CA CRLs for client
        #   authentication or alternatively one huge file containing all
        #   of them (file must be PEM encoded)
        #   Note: Inside SSLCARevocationPath you need hash symlinks
        #        to point to the certificate files. Use the provided
        #        Makefile to update the hash symlinks after changes.
        #SSLCARevocationPath /etc/apache2/ssl.crl/
        #SSLCARevocationFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crl/ca-bundle.crl

        #   Client Authentication (Type):
        #   Client certificate verification type and depth.  Types are
        #   none, optional, require and optional_no_ca.  Depth is a
        #   number which specifies how deeply to verify the certificate
        #   issuer chain before deciding the certificate is not valid.
        #SSLVerifyClient require
        #SSLVerifyDepth  10

        #   SSL Engine Options:
        #   Set various options for the SSL engine.
        #   o FakeBasicAuth:
        #    Translate the client X.509 into a Basic Authorisation.  This means that
        #    the standard Auth/DBMAuth methods can be used for access control.  The
        #    user name is the `one line' version of the client's X.509 certificate.
        #    Note that no password is obtained from the user. Every entry in the user
        #    file needs this password: `xxj31ZMTZzkVA'.
        #   o ExportCertData:
        #    This exports two additional environment variables: SSL_CLIENT_CERT and
        #    SSL_SERVER_CERT. These contain the PEM-encoded certificates of the
        #    server (always existing) and the client (only existing when client
        #    authentication is used). This can be used to import the certificates
        #    into CGI scripts.
        #   o StdEnvVars:
        #    This exports the standard SSL/TLS related `SSL_*' environment variables.
        #    Per default this exportation is switched off for performance reasons,
        #    because the extraction step is an expensive operation and is usually
        #    useless for serving static content. So one usually enables the
        #    exportation for CGI and SSI requests only.
        #   o OptRenegotiate:
        #    This enables optimized SSL connection renegotiation handling when SSL
        #    directives are used in per-directory context.
        #SSLOptions +FakeBasicAuth +ExportCertData +StrictRequire
        <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </FilesMatch>
        <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </Directory>

        #   SSL Protocol Adjustments:
        #   The safe and default but still SSL/TLS standard compliant shutdown
        #   approach is that mod_ssl sends the close notify alert but doesn't wait for
        #   the close notify alert from client. When you need a different shutdown
        #   approach you can use one of the following variables:
        #   o ssl-unclean-shutdown:
        #    This forces an unclean shutdown when the connection is closed, i.e. no
        #    SSL close notify alert is send or allowed to received.  This violates
        #    the SSL/TLS standard but is needed for some brain-dead browsers. Use
        #    this when you receive I/O errors because of the standard approach where
        #    mod_ssl sends the close notify alert.
        #   o ssl-accurate-shutdown:
        #    This forces an accurate shutdown when the connection is closed, i.e. a
        #    SSL close notify alert is send and mod_ssl waits for the close notify
        #    alert of the client. This is 100% SSL/TLS standard compliant, but in
        #    practice often causes hanging connections with brain-dead browsers. Use
        #    this only for browsers where you know that their SSL implementation
        #    works correctly.
        #   Notice: Most problems of broken clients are also related to the HTTP
        #   keep-alive facility, so you usually additionally want to disable
        #   keep-alive for those clients, too. Use variable "nokeepalive" for this.
        #   Similarly, one has to force some clients to use HTTP/1.0 to workaround
        #   their broken HTTP/1.1 implementation. Use variables "downgrade-1.0" and
        #   "force-response-1.0" for this.
        # BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
        #       nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
        #       downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

    </VirtualHost>
    
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        
        ServerName dev.demixer.com

        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/socket            [NC]
        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} transport=websocket    [NC]
        RewriteRule /(.*)           wss://localhost:443/$1 [P,L]
        
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Now when I start the server I don't get any errors but on the client I see:

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://dev.example.com:8080/socket' failed: WebSocket opening handshake timed out
```

Comment: on `linux` to listen on port  `<1024` requires `root` privilege. How are you starting ratchet server ?

Comment: @tinker i'm using putty, `cd /var/www/html/socket` and then `sudo php socket_server.php`

Comment: can you post output of `sudo netstat -ltpn` ?

Comment: Also, `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse` are used to configure apache as reverse proxy. you cannot have reverse proxy and ratchet server configured on same port.

Comment: @tinker i've added the output of netstat -ltpn above. I had found the proxy stuff in another answer when I was looking it up but have removed those two lines now

Comment: ok, so apache is using port `443` as per output of `netstat` on line 
`tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      30191/apache2` .
On your local setup did you use `ws://` or `wss://` ? For a secure connection you will need to configure `SSL` certificate.

Comment: @tinker locally i used ws:// on the server i used wss:// as it does have an SSL cert

Comment: Try other port like 8080 or 8084 ! I face same issue before when trying to access with 443 or 80

Comment: Can you post you full apache configuration if it has `SSL` configured ?  should have a block starting with `<VirtualHost *:443>`

Comment: @tinker thanks for all your help i've added the full config file

Comment: @DavidJawHpan I've switched to 8080 but am still having issues

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming here that you are trying to get websocket working on `dev.demixer.com`. Although you are trying to mask it elsewhere with `dev.example.com`. I noticed the domain name on second config you posted. :)

### First part

Exposing actual domain  helped me figure out that you are using let's encrypt for SSL. I guess you used `certbot` for configuring it on apache ? If so, you still are configuring the wrong file. The file should be something like `dev.demixer.com-le-ssl.conf` under `/etc/apache2/sites-available/`. The file should have configuration like below.

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
    ServerName dev.example.com

Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
#LogLevel warn rewrite:trace5
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/dev.example.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/dev.example.com/privkey.pem

## <-------------------- You need to add all your configuration in this section 
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

### Second part

If you want `wss://` on client you shouldn't add your configuration on  `<VirtualHost *:80>` section. Although its technically possible to specify websocket url like `wss://dev.example.com:80/socket`. This would be a non standard practice as
TCP port 80 is registered for plain `HTTP`. So, lets use port `443`.

### Third part

you don't need `RewriteRule` unless you want fancy URL. For a simpler socket sever configuration you can skip this config all together.

```
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/socket            [NC]
        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} transport=websocket    [NC]
        RewriteRule /(.*)           wss://localhost:443/$1 [P,L]
```

Coming back to your `Ratchet` server configuration it should be started on other port which apache will not be using. So, port other then `80` or `443`.

```php
$server = IoServer::factory(
    new HttpServer(
        new WsServer(
            new socket()
        )
    ),
    8080
);
```

Apache should be configured as a **Reverse Proxy** for your Ratchet server running at port `8080`. The final configuration should look something like below.

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
    ServerName dev.example.com

    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/dev.example.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/dev.example.com/privkey.pem

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass /socket/ ws://0.0.0.0:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse /socket/ ws://0.0.0.0:8080/

</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

And, your client socket url would be `wss://dev.example.com/socket`

### Explanation

A simple diagram how connection is flowing

Browser `wss://dev.example.com/socket` ---> Apache port 443 `/socket` ---> Rachet running on `8080`

The rachet server should be running plain `ws://` connection all the `SSL` layer will be handled by `Apache`. Apache would act similar to [stunnel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stunnel) for websocket

### Bonus Content

If you want to skip apache reverse proxy all together [php ratchet websocket SSL connect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16979793/php-ratchet-websocket-ssl-connect#answer-47200806)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, i'm just getting back to this today, I've tried everything you said here but am still getting an error saying `connection failed: WebSocket opening handshake timed out`