# WebSocket('ws://example.com:8080') works but not WebSocket('wss://example.com:8080')

Tags: websocket, xampp

I need help from the expert and feels like this is beyond my paygrade. I have xampp installed on a windows machine. I have a php page that i access using https://example.com/test.php and inside that php page, it calls a javascript. It did not worked. I got this error:

can’t establish a connection to the server at wss://example.com:8080/

But the everything seems to be working when I access the page as http://example.com/test.php and calls the WebSocket('ws://example.com:8080'). Did I missed anything on my httpd conf?

Thank you

Comment: You need to connect to the HTTPS port, not the HTTP port.

Comment: And which one _is_ your `https` url? `mydomain.com:8080` clearly isn't.

Comment: sorry i forgot to mentioned that yes i was access the url using a https and not http. When i tried to connect, i am getting this error :   can’t establish a connection to the server at wss://mydomain.com:8080/.

Comment: I got that, but again, `mydomain.com:8080` _is the wrong URL_. There is a HTTP server listening on that port, not an HTTPS server.

Comment: hi Tkausl, I just rewrote the question to be more specific.

Comment: It just got more confusing. What exactly is listening on port 8080?

Comment: listening port is port 8080. should i use a different port instead?

Comment: __What__ is listening on port 8080? `listening port is port 8080` How do you know? You have to be a bit more specific about how you got this URL and why you think this is the correct port.

Comment: Thank you Tkausl. Your answer pointed me to the right direction. I found this finally and got it to work.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16979793/php-ratchet-websocket-ssl-connect